# Delphi Indy https request with custom DNS resolving

Tags: delphi, https

example url:
https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time

Using TIdDNSResolver and cloudflare dns I can get the host IP.
direct request in the form of

https://205.251.219.20/api/v1/time

doesn't work cause as I understand the server expects to see "api.binance.com" in the url. (it doesnt work even in browser)

Using synapce and the following patch to replace request's host with resolved IP I make it working

```
function THTTPSend.InternalDoConnect(needssl: Boolean): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := False;
    FSock.CloseSocket;
    FSock.Bind(FIPInterface, cAnyPort);
    if FSock.LastError <> 0 then
      Exit;
    If ResolvedIP.IsEmpty
      then FSock.Connect(FTargetHost, FTargetPort)
      else FSock.Connect(ResolvedIP, FTargetPort);   // !!
```

Is there any way to do the same using Indy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `TIdHTTP` uses the Host:Port that is specified/inferred by the URL that is being requested.  To change that behavior, you would have to alter `TIdHTTP`'s source code, such as in the `TIdCustomHTTP.SetHostAndPort()` or `TIdCustomHTTP.CheckAndConnect()` method (which are both not `virtual`), and then recompile Indy.

Alternatively, you could use `TIdHTTP`'s `OnSocketAllocated` or `On(Before|After)Bind` event (which are not promoted to `published` in `TIdHTTP`, so you would have to access them manually at runtime) to change the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler.Host` property to whatever IP address you want to connect to.  This will not have any affect on the HTTP headers that `TIdHTTP` sends, such as `Host`, which will still be taken from the URL.

Alternatively, if you want all of Indy's Host-to-IP DNS queries to go through Cloudflare, you could derive a custom class from `TIdStack` (or whatever platform-specific descendant you are interested in, such as `TIdStackWindows`), override its virtual `HostByName()` method to perform whatever DNS query you want, and then pass your class type to the `SetStackClass()` function in the `IdStack` unit at program startup before any Indy classes are instantiated.

Comment: The 3d solution is perfect, many thanks!   I didnt want to recompile system code so  `SetStackClass(TCustomStack); ` is exactly what I need.

Comment: please could you add Is there such simple solution for TNetHTTPClient ?

Comment: @MichaelGendelev this should be a new question (this question is specific to the Indy library), but if have the source code for TNetHTTPClient maybe it is possible in a similar way